# How can emulate an IMPLY gate?

Tags: java, boolean-logic

I have a condition that is:

```
#############
| A | B | R |
#############
| T | T | T |
-------------
| T | F | F |
-------------
| F | T | T |
-------------
| F | F | T |
-------------
```

This is an imply gate. How can achieve this in Java?

Comment: `!A || B`. Padding.

Comment: @AndyTurner Can you add as an answer? I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite easy to work out looking at the R column:

- 3 Ts and 1F: `X && Y` would have 3Fs and 1T, so it's `R = !(X && Y)`, for some X and Y.
- The F comes when A is T and B is F; so `X = A` and `Y = !B`, i.e.  `R = !(A && !B)`
- Using [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), that can be simplified to `R = !A || B`.